# Mac OS X "El Capitan": cannot read user set Bash environment variables

Tags: macos, bash, shell, environment-variables, osx-elcapitan

I have a shell script that exports a couple of environment variables that are needed for building a software project (Android Keystore Location).

Usually when I call the script the environment variables are exported, and the IDE can access them, so does the export command on the Bash Terminal.

Since I installed Mac OS X El Capitan, the environment variable set by the Bash command

```
export FOO="bar"
```

are not returned when I try to access them by

```
echo $FOO
```

on the shell. Instead I only get a empty line returned.

If I use `printenv` from within the shell script `$F00` is displayed.

When I call `printenv` from the Cash terminal `$FOO` is missing.

I read that the OS X "El Capitan" updates fixes some security issues concerning bash. Could that be the cause ?

Comment: So you start *Terminal.app*, type `export FOO="bar"` and then `echo $FOO` produces nothing?

Comment: No, that works, but if the `export $F00` is in a shell script, the environment variable is not available outside the script.

Comment: It's not available to apps, for example?  If so, this is well known and covered on this site (where it's off-topic) and also on https://apple.stackexchange.com (where it's on-topic).

Comment: I am using the environment variables to pass on the android keystore location to Android Studio IDE. It used to work fine, but after the update to El Capitan it does not work anymore. Wether the variables are available to other apps I cannot tell, but I was able to get the variables through the bash terminal app before the update, now I cannot.

Comment: @TillKrempel: You realize that you keep alternating between `FOO` (with the letter "oh") and `F00` (with zeros), don't you? If you're making that mistake here, perhaps you're making it in your script or at the shell.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot modify or export variables in the shell with a shebang script (a script whose first line begins with `#!` and the pathname of an executable), if that's what you're doing, because that creates a separate process to execute the script and any variables it exports are only visible to its child processes.

You can only arrange for a script to modify variables in the current shell by executing the script within the current process with `.` (or `source`) for example.

For example, the `~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.bash_logout` scripts are executed directly by the shell, so they can set or export variables to be inherited by commands and sub-shells run from the shell.

Answer (score 0):

I am having a similar issue. It seems that environment variables are not being propagated to child processes from bash. I solved it by explicitly adding the variables I need to the child.

```
export MYVAR=foo
MYVAR=$MYVAR ./executable_to_launch
```

I would be interested to see if someone has found a better solution.

Comment: You have to do this on every login.

Comment: Do not `export` this variable. It is unnecessary and undesirable. When you export a variable, it is inherited by every process you start from the shell. You should only export variables you implicitly expect child processes to read. `X=… command` sets the variable `X` in the command’s process—it exports the variable to just that process. This is the best way to communicate variables to child processes, without spamming all other child processes with an exported variable. Also, in this particular example, exporting it is redundant.